# How to search for words in ACF usign WP-API

Tags: wordpress, search, advanced-custom-fields, wp-api

I'm currently making a website built with Wordpress using WP-API.
The part I get stuck is that I cannot get posts searched by any words in Advanced Custom Fields by using filter[s] which is a parameter officially supported by WP-API.org (http://wp-api.org/#posts_retrieve-posts)

I just tried solving this problem by using "Search Everything" plugin and activated it to add any words in ACF to Wordpress search index, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Could you give me an advice to solve this problem?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Do you have the api link online?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?"